# What is the rationale behind canPlayType?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

So, I recently saw a reference to [canPlayType](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_canplaytype.asp) on Twitter. Basically the summary is:

```
The canPlayType() method checks if the browser can play the specified audio/video type.

The canPlayType() method can return one of the following values:

"probably" - the browser most likely supports this audio/video type
"maybe" - the browser might support this audio/video type
"" - (empty string) the browser does not support this audio/video type
```

Why does it not behave like a typical API and just return true/false?... And why the very ambiguous terms "maybe" and "probably"?

Comment: MDN is ALWAYS better that what you linked to. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

Comment: [This offers some explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504367/difference-between-canplaytype-maybe-and-probably-output)

Comment: yea I know @epascarello .. but there's not way to link to just that method with MDN

Answer (score 0):

Why? Because that is what the spec says to do http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/media-elements.html#dom-navigator-canplaytype

> The `canPlayType(type)` method must return the empty string if type is a type that the user agent knows it cannot render or is the type "application/octet-stream"; it must return "probably" if the user agent is confident that the type represents a media resource that it can render if used in with this audio or video element; and it must return "maybe" otherwise. Implementors are encouraged to return "maybe" unless the type can be confidently established as being supported or not. Generally, a user agent should never return "probably" for a type that allows the codecs parameter if that parameter is not present.

Comment: ...That doesn't make things less confusing ;) Why was this considered a good thing to include in the spec?

Comment: It is the opinion of the people who wrote the spec on why it was done that way. Basically it is a "Cover your butt" way of adding support detection where they do not have a definite end point to determine if it is truly supported.

Comment: They should throw in 'possibly,' 'perhaps,' and ' conceivably' to clear things up.